# Python Cherrypy 404 Error Handling

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a web server that has all of the configurations set in the code, but I want to be able to handle all page 404 errors.  How would I go about doing this in Python?

Comment: Please be more specifc and describe your system in more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a default handler in the root.

```
class Root:
    def index(self):
        return "Hello!"
    index.exposed = True

    def default(self, attr='abc'):
        return "Page not Found!"
    default.exposed = True
```

Comment: How do you send the http 404 header?

Comment: @SeunOsewa cherrypy.response.status = 404

Answer (score 9):

See also http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/ErrorsAndExceptions#AnticipatedHTTPresponses if you want more traditional replacement of 4xx and 5xx output.

Comment: Rather ironically that page is now returning a 404. See here: http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cperror.html?highlight=exception#anticipated-http-responses

Comment: The latest working smnapshot of the original page in archive org: http://web.archive.org/web/20111016122907/http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/ErrorsAndExceptions

Comment: The docs moved once again. For CherryPy 3.2.6 they are located here now: https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/refman/_cperror.html#anticipated-http-responses

Comment: @e1i45 Don't have permission to view that page :-(.

Answer (score 0):

### Anticipated HTTP responses

The 'error_page' config namespace can be used to provide custom HTML output for
expected responses (like 404 Not Found). Supply a filename from which the output
will be read. The contents will be interpolated with the values %(status)s,
%(message)s, %(traceback)s, and %(version)s using plain old Python
`string formatting <http://www.python.org/doc/2.6.4/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations>`_.

::

```
_cp_config = {'error_page.404': os.path.join(localDir, "static/index.html")}
```

Beginning in version 3.1, you may also provide a function or other callable as
an error_page entry. It will be passed the same status, message, traceback and
version arguments that are interpolated into templates::

```
def error_page_402(status, message, traceback, version):
    return "Error %s - Well, I'm very sorry but you haven't paid!" % status
cherrypy.config.update({'error_page.402': error_page_402})
```

Also in 3.1, in addition to the numbered error codes, you may also supply
"error_page.default" to handle all codes which do not have their own error_page entry